# Find Max output of numbers

Tags: python

My problem is that I've got a for loop checking through a string and I want to find the max number in that string but for some reason it sometimes changes the max_ouput to a smaller number. for example if max_output = 254607 and the number its checking is 92186 it will make 92186 the new max_output even though it it not greater.
Code I'm using:

```
    def max_power(data):
        max_output = 0
        lines = data.split('\n')

        for line in lines:
            digits=line.split(',')[-9]
            if digits > max_output:
            max_output = digits
    print max_output
```

This is the data set I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/1UpzeAgD

Comment: Aside: if you had been using Python 3, you would have seen a useful error message -- `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()` -- which would have pointed out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are comparing *string* "254607" with string "92186" string comaprision works character by character and will stop as soon as it decides "9" > "2".

Try

```
if int(digits) > int(max_output):
```

Just needed to int() both

Comment: Yes almost its ' if int(digits) > int(max_output);

Comment: tyty didn't realise it was so easy haha